# Imprimir en pantalla los datos que aparecen entre /* */ como comentario

Tags: c++

La verdad que parece os parecerá una totería de pregunta pero ahi voy:

Tengo que presentar unas prácticas y estoy más perdido que un calamar. El tema es que me piden que los datos que estan como cabecera, los imprima por pantalla, igual que como están.

```
/*******************************************************************************************
NOMBRE: #Juan#
PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez#
SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#
DNI: #11111111#
EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#
*********************************************************************************************/
```

Estos datos tendría que imprimirse por pantalla, pero al ser un comentario, se puede llamar a imprimirlos?

Muchas gracias.
Saludos

Comment: El codigo fuente es otro archivo más, podrías intentar abrirlo, leer las primeras lineas e imprimirlas.

Comment: Y por que no solo haces un std::cout << "/****** DATOS....etc****/";

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que estás empezando a programar creo que lo que te piden es lo siguiente:

```
/**************************************************************************
 NOMBRE: #Juan# PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez# SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#
 DNI: #11111111# EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#
 **************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout   << "/**************************************************************************\n"
           << "NOMBRE: #Juan# PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez# SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#\n"
           << "DNI: #11111111# EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#\n"
           << "**************************************************************************/";
    // resto del código del programa
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quizás le piden solo las líneas con nombre, dni, email, etc. y no las líneas con los asteriscos. No queda muy claro.

Comment: Solo las lineas de Nombre, DNI, etc. Sin asteríscos

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @Lobos es perfecta. Yo solo te doy la alternativa de colocarlo en un string raw, para solo copiar y pegar, asi te complicas menos:

```
/**************************************************************************
 NOMBRE: #Juan# PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez# SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#
 DNI: #11111111# EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#
 **************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char* header =
R"(/**************************************************************************
 NOMBRE: #Juan# PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez# SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#
 DNI: #11111111# EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#
 **************************************************************************/)";

int main()
{
    cout << header << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> pero al ser un comentario, se puede llamar a imprimirlos?

No, el compilador ignora los comentarios. Tienes que reescribirlo, ya sea asi como te lo coloque yo, o como lo coloco @Lobos.

Comment: explicado de maravilla Pablochaches. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que el compilador ignora los comentarios, una alternativa podría ser
generar un encabezado con una función que imprima los datos. Luego, desde
tu código fuente solo bastaria con incluirlo. Por ejemplo:

`main.cpp`

```
/*******************************************************************************
NOMBRE: #Juan#
PRIMER APELLIDO: #Fernandez#
SEGUNDO APELLIDO: #Gonzalez#
DNI: #11111111#
EMAIL: #jantonio.gonzalez@mimail.com#
*******************************************************************************/

#include "printheader.h"

int main() {
    printheader();
}
```

El programa que genera el encabezado es este:

`genheader.cpp`

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: genheader input_file output_file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream input_file(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream output_file(argv[2]);

    output_file << "#ifndef PRINTHEADER_H\n";
    output_file << "#define PRINTHEADER_H\n";

    output_file << "#include <iostream>\n\n";
    output_file << "void printheader() {\n";

    std::string line;

    std::getline(input_file, line); // saltear primera linea

    std::string end = "****************************************"
                      "***************************************/";

    while (std::getline(input_file, line) && line != end) {
        output_file << "    std::cout << \"";

        output_file << std::hex;

        for (unsigned char c : line) {
            output_file << "\\x" << static_cast<unsigned>(c);
        }

        output_file << std::dec;

        output_file << "\\n\";\n";
    }

    output_file << "}\n";

    output_file << "#endif\n";
}
```

Una vez compilado, deberías llamarlo de esta forma:

```
./genheader main.cpp printheader.h
```

El resultado es un archivo parecido a este:

`printheader.h`

```
#ifndef PRINTHEADER_H
#define PRINTHEADER_H
#include <iostream>

void printheader() {
    std::cout << "\x4e\x4f\x4d\x42\x52\x45\x3a\x20\x23\x4a\x75\x61\x6e\x23\n";
    std::cout << "\x50\x52\x49\x4d\x45\x52\x20\x41\x50\x45\x4c\x4c\x49\x44\x4f\x3a\x20\x23\x46\x65\x72\x6e\x61\x6e\x64\x65\x7a\x23\n";
    std::cout << "\x53\x45\x47\x55\x4e\x44\x4f\x20\x41\x50\x45\x4c\x4c\x49\x44\x4f\x3a\x20\x23\x47\x6f\x6e\x7a\x61\x6c\x65\x7a\x23\n";
    std::cout << "\x44\x4e\x49\x3a\x20\x23\x31\x31\x31\x31\x31\x31\x31\x31\x23\n";
    std::cout << "\x45\x4d\x41\x49\x4c\x3a\x20\x23\x6a\x61\x6e\x74\x6f\x6e\x69\x6f\x2e\x67\x6f\x6e\x7a\x61\x6c\x65\x7a\x40\x6d\x69\x6d\x61\x69\x6c\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x23\n";
}
#endif
```

Cada número en hexadecimal es un caracter de los datos. Lo hice de esta forma para no
tener que "escapar" los caracteres conflictivos como la comilla `"` o
la barra invertida `\`.

Despues, cada vez que cambien los datos deberías volver a llamarlo para actualizar
el código. Esto puedes automatizarlo con un *build system* como make, CMake o meson.

Comment: Muchas gracias braver